# socketio and express passport app

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, passport.js

Can someone look in my code and tell what is wrong? 
Im new to node js , but I'm trying to understood it and write app that will authenticate users and serve live data to dashboard. Im stuck on login procedure.

Login screen comes back after post user pass. If I will move function res.flash() it says that needs sesion. 
I spend two days writing this code. Please look.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var flash = require('connect-flash');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

var passport = require('passport');
var signature = require('cookie-signature');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var http = require('http');
var cookie = require('cookie');

// Starting express server

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {});

// Share variables to socket;
var onlineUsers = [];    var dataIO=[];

// MONGOSE DATABASE
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var db = mongoose.connection;

var UserDetail = new Schema({
username: String,
password: String
}, {
collection: 'users'
});
var users = mongoose.model('users', UserDetail);
app.use(flash());
/// PASSPORT
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
var session = require('express-session');
var store = new session.MemoryStore();
var secret = 'secret-session-key';

app.use(session({
secret : secret,
store : store,
saveUninitialized: true,
resave: true}
));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
extended: true
}));

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
   res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
   res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
   res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
   res.locals.user = req.user || null;
   next();
});

app.post('/login',
passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/loginSuccess',
    failureRedirect: '/loginFailure',
})
);

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
done(null, user);
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password'
},
function(username, password, done) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
        // auth logic
        users.findOne({
            'username': username,
        }, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false);
            }
            if (user.password != password) {
                return done(null, false);
            }
            return done(null, user);
        });
    });
}));

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.send('hi');
socket.send('onlineUsers :'+ onlineUsers);

});
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
if (socket.handshake & socket.handshake.headers &             socket.handshake.headers.cookie) {
    var raw = cookie.parse(socket.handshake.headers.cookie)['connect.sid'];
    if (raw) {
        socket.sessionId = signature.unsign(raw.slice(2), secret);
    }
}
if (socket.sessionId) {
    store.get(socket.sessionId, function(err, session) {
       // console.log(session.passport.user.username);
        if (session) {
            if (onlineUsers.indexOf(session.passport.user.username) == -1) {
                onlineUsers.push(session.passport.user.username);
                console.log(onlineUsers);
            }
        }
    });
}
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('disconnecting');
    if (socket.handshake & socket.handshake.headers & socket.handshake.headers.cookie) {
        var raw = cookie.parse(socket.handshake.headers.cookie)['connect.sid'];
        if (raw) {
            socket.sessionId = signature.unsign(raw.slice(2), secret);
        }
    }
    if (socket.sessionId) {
        // console.log(socket.sessionId);
        store.get(socket.sessionId, function(err, session) {
            if (session) {
                // console.log(session);
                console.log(onlineUsers);
                    onlineUsers.splice(onlineUsers.indexOf(session.passport.user.username), 1);
                console.log(onlineUsers);
            }
        });
    }
});
});





// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'layout'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});



module.exports.onlineUsers = onlineUsers;
module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things :

(A) `mongoose.connect()` is an async operation which returns a promise or take a callback. While it allows to start using your models immediately, that is without waiting for mongoose to establish a connection to MongoDB, it is safer to promisify the whole logic to ensure that your connection is open before doing the rest of your code (see http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html for more details)

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb')
    .then(function() {
        // rest of your setup goes here
    }).catch(function(err) {
        // do some error handling
    });
```

(B) when using session, Passport setup should go **after** the call to `app.use(session(...))` (see http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure and scroll down to the "Session" chapter)

```
app.use(session({
    secret : secret,
    store : store,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true}
));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(flash());

/// PASSPORT
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

In my opinion you should regroup all the express app setup together instead of spreading it across your code and launch the server `app.listen()` once all the express config & route setup is done.
Passport's author wrote a good example that you can access here https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-local-example/

(C) You should declare the 2 routes `/loginSuccess` and `/loginFailure` somewhere (I can't see it)

Overall my suggestion would be to clone https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-local-example/ and add complexity progressively from there (replace the example's fake db by mongoose, add socket.io next, ...)

Hope it helps

Comment: Sure it helps, thank You very much. This is the clue, to know exactly what  every module do and how it operates. I start to read documentation, not to write code and thinks goes better. Thank you.